# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr

Tags: spring, solr, spring-data-solr

I am trying to integrate spring and Apache solr. For that i am trying NamespaceHandler http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr. But this giving me the following error.
Can any please help me.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" 
xmlns:solr="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm
http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr/spring-solr.xsd
">
```

This is leading to an error

```
Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr]Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
```

Thanx in advance for any help..

Comment: Try changing "http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr/spring-solr.xsd" to "http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr/spring-solr-1.0.xsd"

Comment: Make sure you have the `spring-data-sold` jars in your class path. @PatrickLC it is recommended to use the version less schema's that way you always have the most recent version of the xsd at your disposal.

Comment: I have added spring-data-solr-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar in my classpath. Which resolved the above mentioned error but there is another error occurring . Mentioning that                       java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtension

Comment: I have added another jar spring-data-commons-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar but this time it is unable to find org.apache.solr.common.SolrException. SolrException is present in the added jars but in a different package which is org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrException. Can any one please help me ..

Comment: You should be using something like maven or gradle to manage your dependencies. You are searching the internet yourself don't.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a new project, you should start from [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) and add Spring Data Solr into it. There are [sample projects](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-solr) of how to do it. You can also check [a real project using Spring Boot, and Spring Data Solr for auto-complete](https://github.com/arafalov/Solr-Javadoc/tree/master/SearchServer).

Comment: But this is an existing project. But probably Spring Boot is not mandatory to be used. Is the any other way to solve this problem.

Comment: Spring Boot was designed to make things simpler, but sure you don't have to use it. Sorry, don't have an answer for your specific setup.